# Php Echo format

Tags: php, html, format

could someone help me format this html code for a php echo?

```
<a href="$title.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]></a>
```

thanks

Comment: Here's a hint: HTML attributes can use single quotes as well as double quotes.

Comment: Here's a hint: PHP strings can use single quotes as well as double quotes

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Yeah, but then the `$title` variable wouldn't expand

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Did not spot $title. Still I'd use `printf();`

Comment: There are dozens of different ways to solve this. I encourage you to [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and repost a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Go and read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

This answers all your string formatting needs in PHP

Here's one way of formatting a string that includes PHP variables and html:

```
"<element id='{$variable}' class='{$array['key']}'>Some {$variableText} text</element>"
```

Another one would be to use the **heredoc syntax** like so:

```
echo <<<STRING
<a href="{$variable}?query={$values['key']}">Some other 'quoted' material</a>
STRING;
```

There are many others, all of which you can find through the link above.

Comment: Please read the tips on [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: I stand by my answer 100%, the link I've provided contains everything the question needs to be understood fully. I'm giving a fishing rod, so to speak, with which the user can solve any future string formatting questions. Thus improving his understanding. Your down vote is completely emotional, but so be it.

Comment: Then post it as a comment. It's not an answer.

Comment: If you'd read the question, the guy is asking for help, I.e. a pointer in the right direction, "could someone help me format...", my answer is entirely that - a pointer. Therefore it perfectly fits into the answer category.

Comment: @morgan - I partly agree with you. Your answer is useful but it also couldn't hurt to provide an example

Comment: @Morgan Wilde, I too believe in *teaching one to fish*. But as it stands, this is not a valuable *answer* as much as it is a valuable *comment*.

Comment: Point taken @KaiQing an example would make this more easy to view as helpful. Jason A while back I had a similar issue with string formatting in PHP and I stumbled until someone gave me the right link, with it I was finally able to understand what's the difference between quotes and so on. My gut feeling was that this is what the guy truly needs and thus my choice for an answer vs. a comment.

Comment: Had to give you a vote up just for the edit to make the answer more useful.

Comment: @njk thanks for making me try harder :)

Comment: @MorganWilde Sorry, meant to say I removed the down vote and giving you an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all `"` with `\"`, then a `"` on either side.

Also, [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is handy to learn.

```
printf('<a href="%s.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]></a>', $title);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf()`, Luke. Do not make your code look crappy with all this nonsense `\"` `"` `'` spaghetti mess:

```
printf( '<a href="%s.php?iframe=true&width=100%%&height=100%%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]></a>', $title);
```

Or (to avoid need to escape `%`), go with pseudo-templating / placeholdering approach (not best performance effective code, but I doubt you need to bother each millisecond at the moment):

```
echo str_replace( '#PAGE", $title, '<a href="#PAGE#.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]></a>');
```

But if you have to use `echo()`, still try to avoid said spaghetti:

```
echo '<a href="' . $title . '.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]></a>';
```

or (from readability standpoint worst possible solution):

```
<a href="<?php echo $title ?>'.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]></a>
```

Comment: Creative, but with all of the above one starts to wonder, why not just drop the html markup in one file, call it template.html, and then just manipulate that file with PHP (say using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). MVC for the win.

Comment: Correct, but that's intentional. My answer is rather for educational purposes (question is quite elementary), just to give OP (or anyone at that level) a picture that such things can be solved in variety of ways...

Answer (score 2):

Just echo complete HTML at once or you can break it.
For complete HTML echo in PHP :

```
<?php echo "<a href='$title.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%' rel='prettyPhoto[partners]'></a>"; ?>
```

or you can:

```
<a href="<?php echo $title;?>.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]"></a>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: its with in a larger list of echos, it wouldnt work.. the empty echo is where the link should sit
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
echo "$body...</p>";
echo "";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

Comment: @john - that sounds like a problem with how you choose to handle output. You're never confined to a "larger list of echos"

Comment: and your updated comment pretty much validates what I just said

Comment: Officially your question asked for help on this particular string, so the top portion of this answer is probably what will work for you with as little modification to the actual code as possible. However, the clean and likely more acceptable way to do this would be easier to demonstrate if you updated your answer with the full chunk of code, or "larger list of echos" so we could show you how to write it properly without having to mess with ugliness

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo $title ?>.php?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[partners]></a>
```